# how to find 6-bit 2’s complement representation of -32

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

I am a new rookie in computer engineering, not sure how to get the 2's complement representation of -32 in 6-bits, because -32 is reaching limit.

Answer (score 1):

For 2's complement, the easiest method is this one:

- write the positive value (here 32) in binary form
- begin to read from the right, and skip all the zeroes until you find the first 1
- leave the one as it is
- keep going left, this time inversing each number (1 => 0, 0 => 1)

Example: -7. 7 is `000111`. The first 1 is on the right, keep it then inverse the rest. You get `111001`.

So in your example, you can't represent -32 with six bits, since the first one is also the last one. Si it will be read `100000` => `-011111` => 31.

You need at least one more bite to avoid overflow (the last bite on the left being the "sign": 0 for positive, 1 for negative).